# Um bom livro para iniciar em python 3

Tags: python

Fala galera, estou querendo iniciar meus estudos em python, ja comecei a fazer o curso do code academy para pegar o básico, mas queria um bom livro para iniciantes, ouvi falar muito bem do "Learn Python the hard way", mas ele se dá em python 2, e pesquisando vi que não há porque voltar para essa versão, sendo assim, gostaria de alguma dica de livro bom semelhante a ele. Alguém sabe?

Comment: João Paulo, existe um livro chamado Think Python. Eu li ele e achei bem instrutivo.